# Setting caption for Virtual Tree List nodes

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I can't understand the process described in documentation. It says to use event:

```
procedure TForm1.VSTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
                Column: Integer; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: WideString);
var
    Data: PTreeData;
begin
   Data:=VST.GetNodeData(Node);
   CellText := Data^.FCaption;
end;
```

How do I do that? I can't redeclare it just like this. When I double click on Tree List `OnGetTextEvent` it throws some exception at me "Property and Method are incompatible"

Comment: Please tell us the exact message. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Well, if i'm not mistaken, GetText is called for drawing the Nodes. But you said the exception is trows when you double click. Do you have some code on your DobleClick event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with my project. I'm not sure what, cos I've recreated it. Now the GetText event works properly. My code above works.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention the Delphi and VirtualTreeview version but I guess thats because of the `CellText: WideString` parameter - it should be of `string` type now after the UnicodeString became the default string type in Delphi. IOW change it to

```
procedure TForm1.VSTGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
          Column: Integer; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
```

Comment: changing it to string doesnt change anything. I use Delphi 2009 and Virtual Tree List 4.8.7